# best approach to make available excel reports to users on Local network

Tags: windows, oracle

For reporting purposes in an organization, someone exports the result of a query on an oracle database, after changing the date parameters every month, and sends the excel on outlook, to a receiver (analyst), there are different receivers (analysts) and different queries with With N:N (many-to-many) relationship between them

I m working on making this process more "automatic", I thought of these approaches:

1. Deploy a web application on my computer, with an Authentication page, then every user is taken to a list of reports that he is allowed to view, then he can choose a maxdate and a mindate value, and then he can download the excel file, with data exported from the oracle database
2. A batch script that's executed every end of the month (or a date chosen by the analysts), executing the oracle query, exporting the result to an excel file: 2.1 And then send the file on outlook 2.2 **OR** save the file on a folder on my computer, and make that file accessible on the local network by the different analysts

I want to get opinions on other approaches (hopefully more minimal and easiest to scale), and what's the pros and cons of the two approaches I've presented, and how I can best implement them

Comment: _"OR save the file on a folder on my computer, and make that file accessible on the local network "   Bad choice on two counts.  1) it is a security risk to be giving others access to your computer.  Second, you are making your own presence a weak link in a critical business process. Suppose you get run over by the proverbial garbage truck.  What would the company do with your workstation, that is now effectively a shared file server for the whole company?

Comment: true, thanks for your answer, I am too leaning towards the first approach, any suggestion on how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option **1** sounds like **Oracle Application Express** (Apex). Even if you aren't an experienced developer, in a matter of a few hours you should be able to create a working web application.

What should you do?

- talk to DBA, ask them to install Apex
- when they provide login credentials to you (presuming they'll also create a workspace for you), create a new application
- you'd mostly use **Interactive Reports**

  - if all data you need is in one table, even better
  - if not, you'll have to write a query which joins several tables, but hey - you already have those queries, haven't you?
  - Interactive Report lets users filter data in various ways
  - you can download result in Excel format so they can analyze data the way they are used to; or, perhaps even better, continue using Apex

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Littlefoot, YES i already have those queries, and I am an experienced developer, I just want to know if Apex has any added value compared with other approaches, the users will only have to download the excel files, and not do anything on the web application for the moment, otherwise, I would think of something like a Shiny application, what do u think?

Comment: I use Oracle so - Apex looks quite OK to me for what you described. I've never used Shiny application so I can't comment it, sorry.

Comment: I'll start with apex then, any good tutorial about apex you can recommend?

Comment: I read official documentation, but I guess there are plenty of videos on YouTube if you want *shortcuts*.